# How to secure XenApp traffic over the internet?

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I am planning to host a client's legacy Line of Business application using a hosted Windows Virtual Server running Citrix XenApp. How do I secure the traffic as it will all pass over the internet? Ideally I would like clients to be able to connect without having to open a VPN connection first. I know Microsoft have the Remote Desktop Gateway but I don't know the Citrix equivalent. Do I need the Citrix Secure Gateway or does XenApp come with some functionality to do this already?

Answer (score 1):

External access to Citrix XenApp (or XenDesktop, for that matter), is usually secured using  [Citrix "Access Gateway"](http://www.citrix.com/products/netscaler-gateway/overview.html), a feature in Citrix NetScaler.

If you only need the Access Gateway, and not the rest of the NetScaler featureset, you can license [NetScaler Gateway VPX](http://store.citrix.com/store/citrix/en_US/buy/productID.281256100/ThemeID.37713000) (virtual appliance) for $1,000 (retail) per instance.

Comment: Am I right in saying that NetScaler Gateway has to be either a physical appliance or run on top of a hypervisor such as VMWare or Hyper-V?

Comment: _NetScaler Gateway_ "is a virtual appliance running on XenServer or VMware ESX/ESXi". The functionality you're looking for is also present in the "full" NetScaler product line, which are phsyical appliances. These are typically used for rather large installations. Check their specs and rated (or licensed) concurrent connections against your need.

Comment: Hmmm, as I suspected. Citrix XenApp isn't really lending itself to a cheaply hosted cloud solution. I was hoping to rent a Windows Virtual Server from someone like FastHosts for a reasonable price and host it all in the cloud. I would probably need a dedicated server for NetScaler Gateway though. I think with MS Remote Desktop the Gateway comes free and the RDS licenses cover it as well. Thanks anyway.